# Get indices of unique WebElements.getText() objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have an `ArrayList<WebElements>` whose elements all have some pieces of text. I'd like to store the indices of those `WebElements`, which contain unique pieces of text in a new `ArrayList<Integer>`. E.g. if the texts are (a,b,c,a,b,d) then I'd need (1,2,3,6).

I tried getting the texts to `ArrayList<String> piecesOfText` with one `stream`, picking the uniques with another one into `ArrayList<String> piecesOfTextUnique`, then looping through `piecesOfTextUnique`and getting the indices of those pieces of text in `piecesOfText` via `indexOf()`

```java
ArrayList<WebElement> webElementsWithText=getWebElements();
ArrayList<String> piecesOfText= new ArrayList<>();
webElementsWithText.stream()
    .map(WebElement::getText)
    .forEach(piecesOfText::add);
ArrayList<String> piecesOfTextUnique = (ArrayList<String>) piecesOfText.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
ArrayList<Integer> uniqueIndeces=new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i< piecesOfTextUnique.size();i++) {
    uniqueIndeces.add(piecesOfText.indexOf(piecesOfTextUnique.get(i)));
}
```

This one does the job, but can someone suggest a more concise/elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `collect` method instead of `Collection#add`-ing in `forEach`.
2. You can not assume that `Collectors.toList` returns `java.util.ArrayList`. It may cause `ClassCastException`.
3. `piecesOfTextUnique` is (semantically) equivalent with `piecesOfText.distinct()`, so `piecesOfText` can be inlined.
4. Last for loop can be replaced with `IntStream`.

So, final result is:

```java
ArrayList<WebElement> webElementsWithText = getWebElements();
List<String> piecesOfTextUnique = webElementsWithText.stream()
    .map(WebElement::getText)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
ArrayList<Integer> uniqueIndeces = IntStream.range(0, piecesOfTextUnique.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> piecesOfTextUnique.get(i))
    .map(s -> piecesOfText.indexOf(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```